# Capturing WACOM Tablet events on a Java Applet

Tags: java, events, permissions, applet, tablet

I'm trying to capture the events of a WACOM tablet, however, by a Java applet.
I've got to do something, but I capture the events as if they were
mouse events.

The problem is that while I am using the tablet to draw in the applet,
I do not want to let him out of the drawing area. From what I read, an Java Applet does not have permission to control the mouse, so I thought that if there was a
way to capture the event of the tablet, maybe I could handle it better.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I read, an Java Applet does not have permission to control the mouse, ..

It does if the applet is digitally signed (by you) & trusted (by the user, when prompted).  Is this functionality vital enough that the end-user would be prepared to OK the trust prompt dialog?

Comment: My applet is signed. Yes, it is vital to the user, and he will trust in my applet. How can I put it to work?

Comment: *"How can I put it to work? "*  Umm.. use the `Robot` to control the mouse (which **is** allowed in a **trusted** applet).

Comment: OK, I got already. Thank you. But, about a tablet API... any info/help? Thanks.

Comment: *"But, about a tablet API... any info/help?"*  Any... real question?  I have no idea what you are asking for there.

Comment: I wanted to do a applet similar to the tablet software. On
software, it's like my drawing area of the tablet, was "projected" in
my area of ​​software design ... It is as if the area of ​​the tablet was directly linked to the software field, the position (x, y) is projected for one to the other ... understand?
I think it's almost impossible to do this in
an applet, but it never hurts to try ...
The real question is: Is there a mode to do this? (PS: I'm not being
clear enough, sorry, my English is not very good). Thanks.